# Command pattern to update private field

Tags: design-patterns, c++, object-oriented-design

I have a class representing the **state** of my application and I want to create many **commands** to update this state.

```
class State{
    private:
        list<int> intList;
    ...
}

class ICommand {
    public:
        virtual ~ICommand(){}
        virtual void execute(State* state) = 0;
}
```

`ICommand` implementations will specify how to update the `state`, so they should interact with its private fields.

**My problem is**: what is the best approach in C++ to let commands update the private field of `State`?

If I expose `intList` with a public getter I can't guarantee that only commands update the state.

If I would use `class friendship` I have to link `State` with command implementation because linking it with the interface does not work and it seems to me not so good...

Is my doubt about 'friendship' unfounded?
Should I choose a different approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, using `friend` declarations is a good choice.

These conditions often arrive with implementations of some design patterns like command, state machine, and strategy. I think of these patterns as extensions of the class holding the state. That is if it was practical, `ICommand` would be part of the `State` class. That means using `friend` in C++.

In many of these cases, I go further and make `ICommand` a nested class within `State`, clearly indicating that these classes are tied together.